# How important is adapting ubuntu with pc parameters?

Tags: installation

I have a project in ubuntu and my topic is " scripts execution in terminal using openmp". I couldnt install openmp because my version of ubuntu did not match with my pc parameters. And now I can't find a version of ubuntu that match with my DELL INSPIRON,processor pentium (R) dual core CPU T4500 @2.30GHz 2.30GHz,OS:32 bit etc...Although I dont know the steps of installing openmp???

Comment: Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Ubuntu work with your PC. Please specify the problems that occur with installing Ubuntu and/or intalling openmp.

Comment: well I think I dont have the right steps of installing openmp.
http://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/installing-openmp-in-linux-debian/ this is the site that Im using and my system doesnt recognize 'gcc'

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you have? Can you please post output of `uname -a` from your terminal?

Comment: anita@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libgomp1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
libgomp1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.

Comment: well then libgomp1 is already installed. From then on you're on your own ;) I've got no clue about openmp.

Comment: The output is: Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libgomp1` entering your password and hitting enter to confirm installation should solve your problem. Note that this is a library only.

Comment: The output is: Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: that's menat for Andrejs Cainikovs I guess

Comment: yes it's for Andrejs :)